# AWS EKS Spring Boot fetch config from remote repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-eks, spring-cloud-config

I have Spring Boot App running an AWS EKS POD fetching configs from remote repo. Everything works fine but the app goes into an endless loop of fetching config from application.yml from the remote repo. It keeps refreshing every millisecond and therefore application log just explodes.

Any ideas what could be the issue here.

Screenshot of the log below: [image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add this

```
health:  
  config:    
    enabled: false
```

to your bootstap.yaml or application.properties file.

If you add this, configs don't fetch when every health check. I am not sure is that your problem caused from health checks but it worths to try

Comment: I tried that, makes no difference, problem persists.